# how to add attributes to a PUT request in GUN?

Tags: gun

I have the following code in my HTML page

```
    Gun.on('opt', function (ctx) {
        if (ctx.once) {
            return
        }
        this.to.next(ctx)
        window.auth = ctx.opt.auth
        ctx.on('get', function (msg) {
            msg.auth = window.auth
            this.to.next(msg)
        })
        ctx.on('put', function (msg) {
            msg.put.auth = window.auth
            this.to.next(msg)
        })
    })

    var gun = Gun({
        peers: ['http://localhost:8765/gun'],
        auth: {
            user: 'mroon',
            password: 'titi'
        }
    })
```

On the server, I simply watch the requests

```
Gun.on('create', function(db) {
    console.log('gun created')
    this.to.next(db);

    db.on('get', function(request) {
        // this request contains the auth attribute from the client
        this.to.next(request);
    });
    db.on('put', function(request) {
        // this request does not contain the auth attribute from the client
        this.to.next(request);
    });
});
```

every time I query the graph with `gun.get('someAttribute')` the request on the server contains the `auth` attribute.

but when a `gun.get('someAttribute').put({attribute: 'my new value'})` is called, the request on the server does not contain the `auth` attribute.

How can I add the `auth` attribute to the `put` request in such a way that all the peers will get it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@micha-roon you jumped straight to GUN's core/internal wire details, which is not the easiest thing to start with, but here is something I do that I'm guessing is what you are looking for:

(if not, please just comment & I'll update)

What this does is it adds a DEBUG flag to all outbound messages in GUN, you can change this to add other metadata or info

```
Gun.on('opt', function(root){
  if(!root.once){
    root.on('out', function(msg){
      msg.DBG = msg.DBG || +new Date;
      this.to.next(msg);
    });
  }
  this.to.next(root);
})
```

Also another good reference: https://github.com/zrrrzzt/bullet-catcher

Comment: thank you. that is more concise than what I had before but it has the exact same behavior: the request in the callback in db.on('get', has an auth attribute while the request in the callback of db.on('put', does not